# GDAL - Register Pixel Function for Command-Line Utilities

Tags: gdal, c++, command-line

I'm new to GDAL and am just learning the inner-workings of C++ compilation at the moment so please bear with me.

I am trying to define a pixel function to produce a VRT from input TIFs, with a band being some computation of other bands, which I can translate into a TIF. Let's say something simple like the min of each band.

The top voted answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/gdal-pixel-functions-question) suggests that these functions cannot exist outside the program where they are registered. There is a nice [post from the GDAL mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-May/028742.html) which summarises the process which suggests otherwise however. This post indicates that I should be able to build a shared library, and define the `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` environment variable to point at the directory containing this. This looks promising, since now a call to `gdal_translate` on the command-line shows that it's trying to access this library but can't find the `GDALRegisterMe` or `GDALRegister_pixelFunctions` function (my library is called `gdal_pixelFunctions.so`)

```
$ gdal_translate testVrt.vrt testVrt.tif
ERROR 1: build/gdal_pixelFunctions.so: undefined symbol: GDALRegisterMe
ERROR 1: build/gdal_pixelFunctions.so: undefined symbol: GDALRegister_pixelFunctions
Input file size is 1000, 1000
0ERROR 5: VRTDerivedRasterBand::IRasterIO:Derived band pixel function 'OneFunction' not registered.
```

My src looks like

```
CPLErr OneFunction(
    void **papoSources,
    int nSources,
    void *pData,
    int nXSize,
    int nYSize,
    GDALDataType eSrcType,
    GDALDataType eBufType,
    int nPixelSpace,
    int nLineSpace
)
{
    // trivial implementation
}

void GDALRegisterMe()
{
    GDALAddDerivedBandPixelFunc("OneFunction", OneFunction);
}
```

Attempting this on Arch Linux if that helps.

EDIT:

In case this is helpful - [This link](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_DRIVER_PATH) shows how GDAL tries to load drivers from shared libraries, searching first for the `GDALRegister_pixelFunction()` function (in this case) and then `GDALRegisterMe()` if not found, but my shared library seems to be failing to provide these for some reason.

Comment: I suggest to ask this question from the gdal-dev mailing list because the GDAL C++ developers are there.

Comment: @user30184 thank you, indeed they were able to quickly point out the issue, posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDAL developer mailing list helped me resolve - simply add

```
extern "C" {
    void GDALRegisterMe();
}
```

to the top of the src file